# Ftd driver for 3dr telemetry radio

Tags: radio-frequency, telemetry

I have been attempting to connect my pixhawk 4 to qgroundcontrol using an old 3DR telemetry radio set. The connection works fine over usb, but qgroundcontrol shows disconnected when I plug in both telemtry radios. I know the radios are connected properly, and both show a solid green light and flashing red when connected the telem 1 port. When connecting to telem 2 it shows solid green but no red. According to the docs, solid green means the radios are connected, and blinking red means data is being transmitted. Therefore, I thought the issue resided in the usb connection. I'm pretty sure I was correct, as when opening the devices menu (I am using Windows 10), there was a yellow triangle next to the device icon, and it could not find a driver. The device was titled F231x usb uart, so I tried to find drivers online, but am struggling to install them. I read they were the same as arduino usb drivers, so I downloaded that. However, there are two inf files, 'ftdibus' and 'ftdiport'. Which do I choose, and how do I install it properly so that the radios will work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FTDI drivers can be downloaded from the [FTDI Website](https://ftdichip.com/drivers/vcp-drivers/).

You should then be able to install the driver using "Update Driver -> Browse my computer for driver software" and selecting the folder containing the extracted files.

Comment: thanks. I didn't realize I needed to select the entire folder